# VS Code shows directory structure instead of app.js file while using Live Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code

I am working on node(Express). **I'm getting my directory structure instead of content. Moreover my browser window isn't getting reloaded too when I save my file.** I don't have any index.html file as I don't need it.

*P.S. I read many related answers on stackoverflow but all those involved index.html relation somehow*
[This is the image of my directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XHli.jpg)

```
var express  = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/',function(req, res){
    res.send("This is Landing page");
});

app.listen(5500, function(){
    console.log("Server has started at port 5500");
});
```

*Code from app.js file*

Comment: post your app.js

Comment: So is this about VS Code or Express?

Comment: try node run app.js

Comment: @xMayank I have pasted app.js

Comment: Run node like this. `node app.js`

Comment: If you want that on each time you save the browser should reload automatically then try "nodemon" instead of "node"

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj did that. Same problem persists.

Comment: @HimanshuBhardwaj Already using nodemon. instead of node app.js.

Comment: @Sigmax everything is working fine at my side

Comment: @juzraai vs code